# break input string seperated inputs for each char

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I am new to angular and im trying to find a way to break one input containing a string to separated inputs (one for each word (split('')). i tried to do it with jquery but couldn't figure it out, plus i understood mixing jquery with angular its not a good approach . 
this is how my input:

```
<td class="name"><input type="text" ng-model="format" ng-blur="savePerson(userName,userId,nameFormat)"/></td>
```

if the input contains "1 test", how can present each char in input of its own??

Comment: each word or each character? What is the expected output if the input is `"1 test"`?

Comment: each char : the result should be each char in its own input field, so if user click on 1 the input field marks only 1 - separated from all the other chars

Answer (score 0):

you can treat a string as an array.

```
var mychars="1 test";
for (i=0;i<mychars.length;i++){
    alert(mychars[i]);
}
```

if you want to display each character in it's own input field:

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4h6wyzhs/1/)

```
var mychars="1 test";

for (i=0;i<mychars.length;i++){

    $('body').append($('<input>').val(mychars[i]));
}
```

Comment: but how does it put each char in its own input field?

Comment: updated my answer to display every character in its own input field.